# LWC - only query when list is null

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to implement a search function. I build a list when the page loads and when a search happens, I want to not query the db again, rather just work with the data already queried. The list in the controller is always null so it never reaches the else block in the controller because accountList is always null.

js:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccount from '@salesforce/apex/AccountListViewController.getAccount';

export default class AccountListView extends LightningElement {

    @track accounts;
    searchKey = '';

    handleKeyUp(evt) {
        const isEnterKey = evt.keyCode === 13;
        if (isEnterKey) {
            this.searchKey = evt.target.value;
            this.displayAccounts();
        }
    }

    displayAccounts() {
        this.accounts = [];
        getAccount({ searchKey: this.searchKey })
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(a => {
                a.AccountUrl = '/lightning/r/Account/'+m.Id+'/view';          
                this.accounts.push(a);

            });    
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        this.displayAccounts();
    }
}
```

controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountListViewController {

    public static List<Account> accountList;

    public AccountListViewController() {}

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> get(String searchKey) {
        if (accountList == null) {
            accountList =  [SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate
                    FROM Account
                    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
        } else {
            //build temp account list from original query based on search field
        }
        return accountList;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always null because each time you call an apex method you start a whole new transaction. Anyway you have that list in JS, so if you want to filter it, you can do it without calling apex. By the way, querying every account in the org may not be the best choice: if there are more than 50k account you'll get an exception, but even 10k might slow down the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am wondering if you are better, having made a call to the server to get all the data you need, to then remain on the client side on your handleKeyUp event.

You can use the filter command on your account object
to do a local search on the data that you have.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

You can then simply update the accounts displayed.

You will need an accounts object to hold all the accounts and then a filteraccounts that you will actually display - so that you can reuse the accounts object as the search criteria change.

Have a look at for a bit more information http://andynix.uk/maps-and-filters-in-a-lwc-component-part-2

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @andy-nix . . . this kinda works

    accounts;
    filteredAccounts = [];
    searchKey;

    handleKeyUp(evt) {
        const isEnterKey = evt.keyCode === 13;
        if (isEnterKey) {
            this.searchKey = evt.target.value;
            this.filteredAccounts = this.missions.filter(this.nameContains);
        }
    }
    nameContains(value) {
        return value.Name.includes(this.searchKey);
    }

I enter the search input and it fails in the nameContains function:

 [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'searchKey')]

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: The above works great until I try to use the search input instead of hard-coding the search value
https://playcode.io/1034714

Comment: This is a sufficient answer for this question. I opened a new ticket to address the issue above while trying to solve this using js filter functionality.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391933/dynamically-update-javascript-variable-to-conduct-search-not-working

Answer (score 1):

```
For this search function implementation you need to follow following steps:
1) First we need to get all records by calling apex wire method. This wire 
   method call in page load automatically.
2) In JavaScript we need handle handleKeyUp() event and filter records based 
   on entered text and then display filtered records on UI.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you only have a few accounts (say less than 10000).

Also, because of the static context that `lwc` calls work with, every call will get you a fresh list of accounts - unless you cache that list. So do this first:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
public static List<Account> getAccounts()
```

This will return the full list of accounts. Make sure you return the `Name` field so you can search it later.

Store this list in your `lwc` component.

```
this.allaccounts = data.map(a => {
    a.AccountUrl = '/lightning/r/Account/'+ a.Id +'/view';          
    return a;
});  
this.filteredaccounts = this.allaccounts;
```

Bind your table of results to `filteredaccounts`;

Finally in your `onkeyup` handler:

```
handleKeyUp(evt) {
  const isEnterKey = evt.keyCode === 13;
  if (isEnterKey) {
    this.filteredaccounts = this.filterAccounts(this.allaccounts,evt.target.value);
  }
}

filterAccounts(accounts, query) {
  return accounts.filter((acct) => 
    acct.Name?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));
}
```

---

If you have more than 10000 accounts, then you will have to query every time.

However, keep the caching on - this will save you some queries if the parameter is the same.

Also, I see that you aren't actually using the param in the query - so add that:

```
searchKey = searchKey + '%';
WHERE Name LIKE :serarchKey LIMIT 10000
```