# dynamically update javascript variable to conduct search not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

html

```
<lightning-input
                        class="slds-float_right slds-m-top_none slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-right_xx-large"
                        onkeyup={handleKeyUp}
                        slot="actions"
                        name="enter-search"
                        label=""
                        type="search"
                        placeholder="Search"
                    ></lightning-input>
```

javascript

```
filteredAccounts = []; 
searchKey; 
handleKeyUp(evt) {
    const isEnterKey = evt.keyCode === 13; 
    if (isEnterKey) { 
        this.searchKey = evt.target.value; 
        this.filteredAccounts = this.accounts.filter(this.nameContains); 
    } 
}

nameContains(value) { 
    return value.Name.includes(this.searchKey); 
}
```

I enter the search input and it fails in the nameContains function:

[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'searchKey')]
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is context and which particular `this` you are referring to.

If you define your handler function as an arrow function, it won't have it's own `this` and will use the parent class `this. Try this:

```
handleKeyUp = (evt) => {
  if (evt.keyCode === 13) { 
    this.searchKey = evt.target.value; 
    this.filteredAccounts = this.accounts.filter(this.nameContains); 
  } 
}
```

If you are not using `this.searchKey` anywhere else, you could skip saving that too:

```
handleKeyUp = (evt) => {
  if (evt.keyCode === 13) { 
    this.filteredAccounts = this.accounts.filter( account => account?.Name.includes(evt.target.value)); 
  } 
}
```

The above example doesn't save the `searchKey` and also uses an inline filter function (`account => account?.Name.includes(evt.target.value)`

Comment: Thanks! the last option worked great.